Items disappear from the cart icon on the home page
I add a product to the cart and when I return to the main page it disappears. Then it goes back to any other URL on the site
I have deactivated lite speed cache, deleted the server cache and nothing, this problem still occurs.
Any solution to this?
Product added
Back to home page
Go to any other URL on the web
Thanks
I have tried clearing the cache and entering specific exclusion codes in lite speed cache to avoid this problem, but it still happens
code
